# (111)Connection refused: mod_fcgid: can't connect unix domain socket

Tags: linux, unix, apache-http-server, proxy, nginx

I have a problem with one of my webservers.

I have Apache and Nginx (like a proxy-reverse server). My Apache run with mod_fcgid for PHP5.3.

All works fine, but **only on a few requests** show me this error on error_log (I set debug LogLevel on Apache):

```
[...] [debug] fcgid_proc_unix.c(544): [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] (111)Connection refused: mod_fcgid: can't connect unix domain socket: /var/run/mod_fcgid/sock/[...]
```

I want emphasize:

- `/var/run/mod_fcgid/sock` is a writable dir. Not apparent permission problem.
- Errors on differents requests and clients.
- **iptables** not contain rules for block or drop connections.

Some ideas?